# How to make kubectl not use AZURE_CLIENT_ID environment variable?

Tags: kubectl, azure-aks, azure-cli

I have `AZURE_CLIENT_ID` environment variable set up on my machine. I have noticed that recently when I run my `kubectl` commands, it requires authentication and tries to do it with the value from that environment variable.

I want it to ignore this value as I think it always did before, so it is something new with the latest `kubectl` or the version that is installed via `az`.

The cluster is deployed in AKS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to avoid using the existed `AZURE_CLIENT_ID` environment variable to make `kubectl` works with the other user login authentication.

***Approach-1***:

You can unset the environment variable if it is not required for some period. Use below `AZ cli` command to unset.

```bash
unset AZURE_CLIENT_ID
```

[image]

***Approach-2***:

As detailed in [kubectl github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-arc/kubernetes/azure-rbac.md#configure-kubectl-with-user-credentials) documentation, you can set the required user credentials and login with `kubectl`, with the below `AZ cli` command as shown.

I provided `--auth-provider-arg` for the `client_id` as an empty string to ignore the existed environment variable. You can modify the value as per the requirement.

Here, I tried to set the credentials for a user named `Jahnavi` with an empty `client-id` value and the user was successfully set as follows:

```bash
kubectl config set-credentials <jahnavi> --auth-provider=azure --auth-provider-arg=environment=AzurePublicCloud 
--auth-provider-arg=CLIENT_ID=  --auth-provider-arg=tenant-id="tenantID"
```

[image]

***Approach-3***:

If still the issue persists, you can directly view the config file and edit the user credentials by executing `kubectl config view` command.

It will display the Kubernetes configuration file contents, as well as the file's path. After that, you can update the file to remove the Azure credentials accordingly.

```bash
kubectl config view
```

[image]

You can also refer this [document](http://erictune.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_config_set-credentials/#:%7E:text=kubectl%20config%20set-credentials%20Sets%20a%20user%20entry%20in,Client-certificate%20flags:%20%E2%80%93client-certificate=certfile%20%E2%80%93client-key=keyfile%20Bearer%20token%20flags:%20%E2%80%93token=bearer_token) for more related information.

Comment: I have tried to use the approach 2 (since I want to it to always ignore the env variable), but this is what I am getting:

error: authProvider cannot be provided in combination with an exec plugin for clusterUser_<resource_group>_<cluster_name>.

So what I am trying to achieve is that kubectl would always work like if AZURE_CLIENT_ID does not exist even if it does. This is how it worked earlier, and I assume there was some change

Comment: For me it was working @IlyaChernomordik without any issue. So if you want to ignore the env variable you can simply unset it as I mentioned in the first approach. Did that works?

Comment: Yes, that works just fine, thank you, it is just inconvenient to do it every time...

Comment: Can you check & update the kubectl version and related one's because in few api versions these combination is deprecated. Check with the `kubectl version` command and update it if needed. @IlyaChernomordik

Comment: I have client 1.26.3 and server 1.24.3. There are 2 major version differences but I guess this should not be a problem since it is kubelogin that reads these env. variables?

Comment: Thanks for help, I am using "unset" so far and it works. Did not manage with the other approaches unfortunately